# Como mudar cor padrão da área que aparece quando ocorre scroll na tela?

Tags: flutter, dart, ui

[image: Área azul na tela]

Na tela inicial desse aplicativo utilizo um SliverAppBar e quando realizo um Scroll em tela essa área/sombra azul aparece. Qual é o nome dessa área?

Quero permitir ao usuário escolher uma cor padrão para a sombra dentro do app. Além disso, quando ele navegar para uma outra tela, o mesmo poderá salvar uma cor padrão para a sombra daquela tela em que se encontra. Logo, o app poderá aplicar diferentes cores à sombra.

Como faço isso da maneira correta?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NoteScreenState createState() => _NoteScreenState();
}

class _NoteScreenState extends State<NoteScreen> {
  var _sliverAppBar = SliverAppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    shadowColor: Colors.black,
    pinned: true,
    title: Text('Title'),
    expandedHeight: 200,
    stretch: true,
    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
      background: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/warrior.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            _sliverAppBar,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: É só passar a cor desejada para a propriedade `accentColor` do `ThemeData`.

Comment: @user140828 Coloca como resposta para eu colocar como certa.